# AngularJs directives call link function on click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am wondering how to specify when the link function for a directive should be called.

Currently I have the following code:

```html
<my-directive username="abc"></my-directive>
```

```html
module.directive("myDirective", [{
  restrict: "A",
  link($scope, element, others) {
    //if element.clicked() {
    //  console.log("you clicked me");
    //}
  }
}]);
```

As you can see I have commented out pseudo-ish code of what I would like to do and I have seen that it's possible to do something like element.onClick = function() {}. But this still doesn't seem to be called when the element is clicked.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
element.on('click', function() {});
```

Angular uses build in [jQuery Lite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element), so you can use this.

Comment: You're right, that's my fault. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @SwimmingG thanks, please don't forget to mark the answer as your solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.abc = 'abc';
    
});



app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      username: '='
    },
    link:link,
    template: '<div>Click Here</div>'
  };
  function link(scope,elem,others){
    
     elem.bind('click', function() {
      console.log('on click');
    });  
    
  }
});
```

```html
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script data-semver="1.4.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.4.x"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

   <body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <my-directive username="abc"></my-directive>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also try like this!

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.abc = 'abc';
    
});



app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      username: '='
    },
    link:link,
    template: '<div ng-click="click()">Click Here</div>'
  };
  function link(scope,elem,others){
    
   scope.click = function() {
        console.log('on click', scope.username);       
   }
  }
});
```

```html
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script data-semver="1.4.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.4.x"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

   <body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <my-directive username="abc"></my-directive>
  </body>
```